# How to Choose a specific value from a table and to avoid duplicates?

Tags: algorithm, debugging, oracle11g

I have two tables:

MainTable

```
id AccountNum  status

1  11001   active
2  11002   active
3  11003   active
4  11004   active
```

AddTable

```
id  date     description
1  01.2020   ACCOUNT.SET
1  02.2020   ACCOUNT.CHANGE
1  03.2020   ACCOUNT.REMOVE
2  04.2020   ACCOUNT.SET
2  05.2020   ACCOUNT.CHANGE
3  08.2020   ACCOUNT.SET
4  05.2020   ACCOUNT.SET
4  09.2020   ACCOUNT.REMOVE
```

I need to get a such result:

**EffectiveFrom** is date when Account was set,
**EffectiveTo** is date when Account was removed

```
id AccountNum EffectiveFrom  EffectiveTo
1  11001       01.2020         03.2020
2  11002       04.2020          null 
3  11003       08.2020          null
4  11004       05.2020         09.2020
```

The problem is that after joining on AddTable I get the duplicates, but I need just one row on every Id and only dates where the description in ACCOUNT.SET,ACCOUNT.REMOVE.

Comment: Can you show your query?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `left join`?

```
  select m.id         as id,
         m.AccountNum as AccountNum,
         a.date       as EffectiveFrom,
         b.date       as EffectiveTo
    from MainTable m left join
         AddTable a on (a.id = m.id and a.description = 'ACCOUNT.SET') left join
         AddTable b on (b.id = m.id and b.description = 'ACCOUNT.REMOVE') 
order by m.AccountNum
```

Comment: Suppose, yes. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PIVOT` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT m.id,
       a.EffectiveFrom,
       a.EffectiveTo
FROM   MainTable m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT *
         FROM   AddTable
         PIVOT( MAX( dt ) FOR description IN (
           'ACCOUNT.SET' AS EffectiveFrom,
           'ACCOUNT.REMOVE' AS EffectiveTo
         ) )
       ) a
       ON ( a.id = m.id )
ORDER BY m.id
```

So for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MainTable ( id, AccountNum, status ) AS
SELECT 1, 11001, 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 11002, 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 11003, 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 11004, 'active' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE AddTable ( id, dt, description ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-01', 'ACCOUNT.SET' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-02', 'ACCOUNT.CHANGE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-03', 'ACCOUNT.REMOVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-01-04', 'ACCOUNT.SET' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-01-05', 'ACCOUNT.CHANGE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-01-08', 'ACCOUNT.SET' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2020-01-05', 'ACCOUNT.SET' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2020-01-09', 'ACCOUNT.REMOVE' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID | EFFECTIVEFROM | EFFECTIVETO
> -: | :------------ | :----------
>  1 | 01-JAN-20     | 03-JAN-20  
>  2 | 04-JAN-20     | null       
>  3 | 08-JAN-20     | null       
>  4 | 05-JAN-20     | 09-JAN-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c6af4c060f3e99a477cffb81998de08f)*